# How is critical rating calculated in Wizard101?

Tags: wizard101

I have around 30 critical rating in Wizard101. Is that the percent of chance of critical?
Or is it how much extra damage?

Comment: How accurate is this as of Nov, 2015?

Comment: This information is no longer accurate. Critical chance decays as level increases.

Answer (score 4):

The way critical rating is calculated is that 500 = 100% of critical.
So, 30 would be a 6% chance.

Its basically like this:

500 = 100
30  = x

where x is the % of critical.

If you get a critical, you deal double the damage you would have normally done.

Answer (score 1):

Divide your critical strike rating by 5 and that is the percent chance you will critical.